# What is --direct mode in sqoop?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2, sqoop, sqoop2

As per my understanding sqoop is used to import or export table/data from the Database to HDFS or Hive or HBASE.

And we can directly import a single table or list of tables. Internally mapreduce program (i think only map task) will run.

My doubt is what is sqoop direct and what when to go with sqoop direct option?

Answer (score 6):

Just read the Sqoop documentation!

- General principles are located [here](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_controlling_the_import_process) for imports and [there](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_syntax_4) for exports

> Some databases can perform **imports** in a more high-performance fashion
>   by using database-specific data movement tools *(...)*
>
> ---
>
> Some databases provides a direct mode for **exports** as well *(...)*
>
> ---
>
> Details about use of direct mode with each specific RDBMS, installation requirements, available options and limitations can be found in Section 25

- Section 25 under [MySQL](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_mysql_direct_connector)
- Section 25 under [Oracle data connector for Hadoop](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_about)
- etc.

Bottom line: "direct mode" means **different things for different databases**.
For MySQL or PostgreSQL it relates to bulk loader/unloader utilities (i.e. completetely bypassing JDBC); while for Oracle it relates to "direct path INSERT" i.e. with JDBC but in a non-transactional mode *(so you'd better use a temp table, or you might end up with duplicates in a PK and a corrupt table)*.

Answer (score 3):

To be short and precise,its the mode for fast import which doesn't runs any mappers or reducers.

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://db.foo.com/corp --table EMPLOYEES --direct
```

Notes:

1. `--direct` is only supported in mysql and postgresql.
2. Sqoop’s direct mode does not support imports of `BLOB`, `CLOB`, or `LONGVARBINARY` columns.

Comment: Note 1 is not correct. Direct Mode is also supported for Netezza Connectorfor v1.4.4+. [Documentation reference](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.4/SqoopUserGuide.html#_direct_mode)

Answer (score 2):

From [Managing Big Data in Clusters and Cloud Storage](https://www.coursera.org/learn/cloud-storage-big-data-analysis-sql/)

> By default, Sqoop uses JDBC to connect to the database. However,
>   depending on the database, there may be a faster, database-specific
>   connector available, which you can use by using the [--direct
>   option](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html#_connecting_to_a_database_server).

So, you go with **--direct** option when you want to use a different database connector than the default.

Answer (score 1):

`--direct`  - Use direct import fast path

[By supplying the `--direct` argument](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_controlling_the_import_process), you are specifying that Sqoop should attempt the direct import channel. This channel may be higher performance than using JDBC.

**For MySQL:**

MySQL Direct Connector allows faster import and export to/from MySQL using `mysqldump` and `mysqlimport` tools functionality instead of SQL selects and inserts.

Details about use of direct mode with each specific RDBMS, installation requirements, available options and limitations can be found in [Section 25, “Notes for specific connectors”.](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#connectors)

Answer (score 1):

You can improve the performance by giving `--direct` option in sqoop

But do not use it for non-priority jobs as more usage of direct may bring down the source/target DB

http://archive.cloudera.com/docs-backup/sqoop/_direct_mode_imports.html